# How can I automount cd in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, automount, cd

The problem is that my music CDs, and also try with virgin-CDs, do not mount automatically when I insert them. I have to mount them from nautilus and after that I'm ready to listen to it in rhythmbox. It's very irritating...

Need some help please.

Thanks.

Comment: Reading some forums, I realized that I have no haldaemon service in my machine. And when a try to install it I get this error..

Answer (score 1):

Go to dash, then find (just type) *startup programs* and lauch it. It will bring the list with your startup programs. Find something called *mount assistant* and if it is not checked, check it and restart ubuntu.

You can paste this in terminal to see your full autostart:

> sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop

and then start again startup programs

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don`t understand. Where can I find that option?

Comment: Sorry, but there is not mount assistant in startup programs

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal.

Run it:

```
sudo -i
nano /etc/fstab
```

Check the file you have to cd/dvd drive these options:

```
/dev/scd0     /media/cdrom0    udf,cdfs,iso9660   user,auto,exec,utf8   0   0
```

Control + O, save file. Control + X, close nano.

Close a terminal.

In addition

Go to a file manager window ---- You click on somewhere in Places ---- Go to Edit ---- Preferences ---- Media ----- Tick the box for Browse media when inserted.

And

Goto System ---- Adminstration ---- Users and Groups ---- Add the current user to haldaemon.

Comment: I have no haldaemon. I`m trying to install it but i get this error:                                                                                                                           """""El paquete hal no está disponible, pero algún otro paquete hace referencia
a él. Esto puede significar que el paquete falta, está obsoleto o solo se
encuentra disponible desde alguna otro origen
Sin embargo, los siguientes paquetes lo reemplazan:
  hal-info

E: El paquete «hal» no tiene un candidato para la instalación"""

Comment: The hal package is not available, but some other package refers to it. This may mean that the package is missing , has been obsoleted , or is only available from some other source However the following packages replace it : hal -info E: The package ' hal ' has no installation candidate

Comment: How can I install hal ?

Comment: Hal has been deprecated for ~10 years.