# Cannot mount CDs after update to 15.10

Tags: mount, cd, 15.10

After the update, CDs are not automatically mounted, although DVDs are. The physical drive, however, is recognized:

*-cdrom

```
   description: DVD-RAM writer
   product: DVDRAM GSA-H42L
   vendor: HL-DT-ST
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/cdrom
   logical name: /dev/cdrw
   logical name: /dev/dvd
   logical name: /dev/dvdrw
   logical name: /dev/sr0
   version: SL00
   capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
   configuration: ansiversion=5 status=ready
 *-medium
      physical id: 0
      logical name: /dev/cdrom
```

Mounting manually the CDs through the command line (using mount -t iso9660 /dev/cdrom) also works, but it's inconvenient...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I automount cd in Ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/530981/how-can-i-automount-cd-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the files /etc/fstab and /etc/mtab? If you are able to mount manually then I'll bet the mount parameters for your device are missing in these 2 files and automounting will not occur without the mount parameters are in at least 1 of these 2 files. 
  To edit these files, go to a terminal and type in " sudo gedit /etc/fstab " (sans quotes). Enter your password when asked and the file will open in gedit, ready to edit as needed.
  man mount, man fstab, and man mtab can also be helpful for particulars as well, but the command that you spoke of using to manually mount appended to the files should put this problem to rest. Hope this helps  Craig

Comment: Thank you. Editing the fstab file solved the problem. However, this doesn't explain why automounting occurred for DVDs and not for CDs or why upgrading to 15.10 messed these settings...